# Check for a valid guid

Tags: vbscript, guid

How can you check if a string is a valid GUID in vbscript? Has anyone written an IsGuid method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is similar to the [same question in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104850/c-test-if-string-is-a-guid-without-throwing-exceptions#104932). Here is the regex you will need...

^[A-Fa-f0-9]{32}$|^({|()?[A-Fa-f0-9]{8}-([A-Fa-f0-9]{4}-){3}[A-Fa-f0-9]{12}(}|))?$|^({)?[0xA-Fa-f0-9]{3,10}(, {0,1}[0xA-Fa-f0-9]{3,6}){2}, {0,1}({)([0xA-Fa-f0-9]{3,4}, {0,1}){7}[0xA-Fa-f0-9]{3,4}(}})$

But that is just for starters. You will also have to verify that the various parts such as the date/time are within acceptable ranges. To get an idea of just how complex it is to test for a valid GUID, look at the source code for one of the Guid constructors.

Comment: Literal parenthesis need to be escaped. For example, the second subexpression should be `|^({|\()?[A-Fa-f0-9]{8}-([A-Fa-f0-9]{4}-){3}[A-Fa-f0-9]{12}(}|\))?$` instead of `|^({|()?[A-Fa-f0-9]{8}-([A-Fa-f0-9]{4}-){3}[A-Fa-f0-9]{12}(}|))?$`.

Answer (score 3):

This function is working in classic ASP:

```
Function isGUID(byval strGUID)
      if isnull(strGUID) then
        isGUID = false
        exit function
      end if
      dim regEx
      set regEx = New RegExp
      regEx.Pattern = "^({|\()?[A-Fa-f0-9]{8}-([A-Fa-f0-9]{4}-){3}[A-Fa-f0-9]{12}(}|\))?$"
      isGUID = regEx.Test(strGUID)
      set RegEx = nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

In VBScript you can use the RegExp object to match the string using regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Techek's function did not work for me in classic ASP (vbScript). It always returned True for some odd reason. With a few minor changes it did work. See below

```
Function isGUID(byval strGUID)
  if isnull(strGUID) then
    isGUID = false
    exit function
  end if
  dim regEx
  set regEx = New RegExp
  regEx.Pattern = "{[0-9A-Fa-f-]+}"
  isGUID = regEx.Test(strGUID)
  set RegEx = nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score -4):

there is another solution:

```
try
{
  Guid g = new Guid(stringGuid);
  safeUseGuid(stringGuid); //this statement will execute only if guid is correct
}catch(Exception){}
```