# Tracking events using Google Analytics in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics-api

I would like to track an event in Wordpress when the user clicks on a download link.

Here's the code I'm using

```
<a href="http://myurl.com/filetodownload.zip" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'download', 'files', 'myfile', 0, false]);">My file to download</a>
```

This code is in a Wordpress post.

The problem I'm having is that when I load the page the `onClick` value is `_gaq.push()`;

So I lost all the contents. This happens only when the code is inside a Wordpress post. Things work properly when I put the tracking code in the template.

Any ideas on how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

What about attaching a css class to the link inside your Wordpress post, then tying a jQuery event to that. You could use title attribute inside your link to grab parameters for each link. Something like this:

The link in WP:

```
<a href="http://myurl.com/filetodownload.zip" class="googleclick" title="Myfile">My file to download</a>
```

Inside your header: Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('a.googleclick').click(function(){

    var fileName = $(this).attr('title');
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'download', 'files', fileName, 0, false]);

    });
});
```

I'm not 100% familiar with all the parameters, and how many links you have inside your post, but that may get you started.

Alternatively, you may want to look at this:

http://www.wprecipes.com/disable-wordpress-automatic-formatting-on-posts-using-a-shortcode

Which gives a way to handle post reformatting in WP.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately adding the jQuery code didn't change anything. I ended up using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481176/tracking-a-download-button-click-with-analytics-using-events