# How to validate Guid in .net

Tags: c#

Please tell me how to validate GUID in .net and it is unique for always?

Comment: Guid's are always unique if all the generators play by the rules: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/06/27/8659071.aspx

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Guid's are unique 99.99999999999999999999999999999999% of the time.

It depends on what you mean by validate?

Code to determine that a Guid string is in fact a Guid, is [as follows](https://web.archive.org/web/20210123224013/http://geekswithblogs.net/jawad/archive/2005/05/20/GuidVerifier.aspx):

```
private static Regex isGuid = 
      new Regex(@"^(\{){0,1}[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}(\}){0,1}$", RegexOptions.Compiled);

internal static bool IsGuid(string candidate, out Guid output)
{
    bool isValid = false;
    output = Guid.Empty;

    if(candidate != null)
    {
   
        if (isGuid.IsMatch(candidate))
        {
            output=new Guid(candidate);
            isValid = true;
        }
    }

    return isValid;
}
```

Comment: +1 for trying not to use exceptions, -1 because a `Guid` can have other formats and the current method will throw an exception for the following case: "{230a0f8b-81fb-4052-866e-9ac6a7611c77"

Comment: +1, In .NET 4.0, we'll finally see the introduction of `Guid.TryParse()`, which would obviously be preferable to using a Regex. For now though, this is perfectly sufficient and acceptable.
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/94072/guid-tryparse

Comment: Guid's are not random, maybe there's a way to also check if they meet these criteria: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/06/27/8659071.aspx

Answer (score 13):

2^128 is a very, very large number.  It is a billion times larger than the number of picoseconds in the life of the universe.  Too large by a long shot to ever validate, the answer is doomed to be "42".  Which is the point of using them: you don't have to.  If you worry about getting duplicates then you worry for the wrong reason.  The odds your machine will be destroyed by a meteor impact are considerably larger.

Duck!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a non-Regex answer that should be pretty fast:

```
public static bool IsHex(this char c)
{
    return ((c >= '0' && c <= '9') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F'));
}

public static bool IsGuid(this string s)
{
    // Length of a proper GUID, without any surrounding braces.
    const int len_without_braces = 36;

    // Delimiter for GUID data parts.
    const char delim = '-';

    // Delimiter positions.
    const int d_0 = 8;
    const int d_1 = 13;
    const int d_2 = 18;
    const int d_3 = 23;

    // Before Delimiter positions.
    const int bd_0 = 7;
    const int bd_1 = 12;
    const int bd_2 = 17;
    const int bd_3 = 22;

    if (s == null)
        return false;

    if (s.Length != len_without_braces)
        return false;

    if (s[d_0] != delim ||
        s[d_1] != delim ||
        s[d_2] != delim ||
        s[d_3] != delim)
        return false;

    for (int i = 0;
        i < s.Length;
        i = i + (i == bd_0 ||
                i == bd_1 ||
                i == bd_2 ||
                i == bd_3
                ? 2 : 1))
    {
        if (!IsHex(s[i])) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot validate GUID's uniqueness. You just hope it was generated with a tool that produces unique 16 bytes. As for validation, this simple code might work (assuming you are dealing with GUID's string representation:

```
bool ValidateGuid(string theGuid)
{
  try { Guid aG = new Guid(theGuid); }
  catch { return false; }

  return true;
}
```

Comment: Thats the easy way out. Remember that Exceptions should be used for exceptional circumstances, not for validating types.

Comment: @Kyle Rozendo: Yeah, but with Regex, you pretty much limit the format of GUID's string representation. For example, in your code, the formatting is WITH DASHES only.

Comment: Yeah, we would never want to take "the easy way out" when writing tons of code to do the same thing is so much better... What if this was a unit test? Would it then be acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a way to determine if it's the format of the actual .Net `Guid` type, [take a look at this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20130818124721/http://madskristensen.net/post/Validate-a-GUID-in-C.aspx).  A quick regex does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

this question was already discussed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104850/c-test-if-string-is-a-guid-without-throwing-exceptions). You may find more interesting details

Answer (score 0):

In .net 4, you can use this extension method

```
public static class GuidExtensions
    {
        public static bool IsGuid(this string value)
        {
            Guid output;
            return Guid.TryParse(value, out output);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i wrote a extension for this

```
public static bool TryParseGuid(this Guid? guidString)
       {
           if (guidString != null && guidString != Guid.Empty)
           {
               if (Guid.TryParse(guidString.ToString(), out _))
               {
                   return true;
               }
               else
                   return false;
           }

           return false;
       }
```

Comment: Method name `TryParseGuid` would usually suggest that parsing output is returned as out parameter (like `Enum.TryParse` etc.). Think of renaming this extension method to `IsGuidValid` or similar, which will clearly indicate that it returns `bool`