# possible to convert string to GUID?

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I have a dropdownlist selection, selected value will be ID, type is GUID, currently my code for the select button is

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim Selection As String = Nothing

    If Not DropDownList3.SelectedValue Is Nothing Then Selection = DropDownList3.SelectedValue

    Session("Selected") = Selection

End Sub
```

then I have

```
Dim ID is guid
ID = Session("Selected")
```

then i need to execute sql such as `select * from .. where ID=..`
Problem happens at `ID = Session("Selected")`, as `ID` is `GUID`, while `Session("Selected")` is `string`
I wonder if there is a way to handle it?
Thanks very much for help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#: Test if string is a guid without throwing exceptions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104850/c-test-if-string-is-a-guid-without-throwing-exceptions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this method:

```
GUID myGuid;
object myObj = Session("Selected");

if (myObj != null && Guid.TryParse(myObj.ToString(), out myGuid))
{
   //input is good, do stuff here
}
else
{
   //input is bad, handle error
}
```

I hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: I tried ID = Guid.Parse(Session("Selected")), but when debug has an error saying Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: input ?

Comment: The first check if the session object is not null. If it is null, you will have to check the method where you are setting it.

Comment: I guess the default value is null? At the beginning nothing is selected in dropdownlist. I guess if i set ID to be GUID type, then I have to set a not null defaulted value for dropdownlist?

Comment: You could set the initial value for the dd list to be null. When you are testing it, and its null, you know that it is the initial selection, 'Please select...'

Comment: Much appreciated for your help!

Comment: NP. Good luck coding!